# Explain the usage of C-c C-s in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex

[AUCTeX manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Sectioning.html)

> Command: LaTeX-section *arg*
>
> (C-c C-s) Insert a sectioning command.
>
> • If *arg* is a list (selected by C-u), go downward one level.

What does it mean? I've tried `C-u <several keys> C-c C-s` but never got it to work.

Comment: See the Elisp Manual node on [Prefix Command Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) for clarification on the different values the prefix argument can take.

Comment: @Basil Thanks, I had read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html but I didn't find the answer, so I asked here, then I found the answer in the page you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was just a matter of typing `C-u` twice before `C-c C-s`.